# Regular expression split (|)

Tags: java, regex, split

I send a string `"hello,145451,new,5565"` by commas with this expresion `",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` and this run correct with this result:

hello
145451
new
5565

it returns four elements.

but now I need to separate `"hello|145451|new|5565"` by `|`

I use this expression: `"\\|(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` and the result is:

hello|145451|new|5565

it return only one element

Can anyone help me?

Comment: String[] split = "hello|145451|new|5565".split("|");

Comment: not found this, I would like replace this expression ",(?=(?:[^\"]\"[^\"]\")[^\"]$)" but separated by "|"

Comment: [Your code works as expected](http://ideone.com/rZZkCa). `"\\|(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` correctly splits with `|` outside of double quotes (the regex is not efficient though, a CSV parser is highly recommended in this case).

Comment: yes! it's running perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe `|` is a metacharacter in regex, add double backslash to split strings based on pipe.

```
String str = "hello|145451|new|5565";
String arr[] = str.split("\\|(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

for(String myStr: arr) {
    System.out.println(myStr);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this but not found

Comment: Split by `|` you want get result `hello` `145451` `new` `5565` ? It should work fine.

Comment: anyway I would like replace this expression ",(?=(?:[^\"]\"[^\"]\")[^\"]$)"  and I tried with "\\|" but not found...

Comment: @danievel i've updated the code, use `forEach` for solving your problem.